# CSS Bootstrap - Text not breaking correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div block on the top of my website where I want to display a logo and some info, like telephone number etc.

Here you can take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/7f8gc17o/

I wanted the text (telephonenumber, emailaddress) to be vertically centered, so I did this:

```
.headerinfo {
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

This was working great, but when I now resize the window, the text wont break. It just will stay there and the logo gets really, really small. When a user has a small screen, I want to display the information below. Logo on the top, followed by the information.

Secondly, what I have noticed: I have some kind of a headline (which I added the class "skyblue") - when I resize the window, the second text-line ("Hier finden Sie uns") breaks. But I want the headlines displayed next to each other, as long as there is enough space.

How do I do that? Help would be really appreciated.

Thank you for reading

Comment: not sure if this is what you are after but have you tried adding 
`flex-wrap:wrap;` to `headerinfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using **Media Queries**. And change the `flex-direction` to `column` on mobile. Like:

```
/* On Mobiles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .headerinfo {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@color-purple: #292657;
.purple-container,.headline-container{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: @color-purple;
 div.icon-container{
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  h2{
   margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
  .thumbnail{
   background-color: transparent;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 0;
   >img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
   }
   >.caption{
    color: @color-white;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 30px;
   }
  }
 .text-container{
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  >p{
   >.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
   }
  }
 }
 }
}

.font-bigger{
 font-size:18px;
}

.skyblue{
 color: #d2e5e9;
 font-size: 20px;
}

/*this causes the main problem*/

.headerinfo {
 height: 250px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

/* On Mobiles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .headerinfo {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .logo-img {
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
   <div class="container purple-container text-center" style="margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row headerinfo">
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="logo-img" src="../img/Andreas_Heinke_Logo.png" alt="Some picture" style="width:auto;height:auto;max-width:100%;"/>
     </div>

     <div class="col-md-3 font-bigger">
      <strong class="skyblue">Wir beraten Sie gern:</strong><br>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone icon-margin"></span>01234 567 89 012<br>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope icon-margin"></span>info@email.de
     </div>


     <div class="col-md-3 text-center font-bigger">
      <strong class="skyblue">Hier finden Sie uns:</strong><br>
      Streetname<br>
      01234 City
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
      </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! But how did you manage the headlines staying next to each other? Because when I resize my window (before the breakpoint) it does this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yc4w2vp2f8hu1jj/headline_break.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @Insane Is this case happening with the code above that I posted?

Comment: No, it doesn't - but in my fiddle. That's why I wanted to know if you changed anything else in your code

Comment: @Insane No I don't changed anything except the logo image `margins top/bottom` on mobile. That's It. You can see the snippet above. Also don't forgot to accept this as your answer if this helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

To centre the image, apply this style to it:

margin:0 auto

To centre the text, apply this style to it:

text-align: center